# Customizing a MonetaryAmountFormat using the Moneta (JavaMoney) JSR354 implemenation

Tags: java, jsr354

I'm really confused about how to customize a `MonetaryAmountFormat` using the Moneta JSR-354 implementation.

My intention is to be able to parse both `1.23` and `$3.45` as `MonetaryAmount`s.

Here is my unit test:

```
@Test
public void testString() {
    Bid bid = new Bid("1.23");
    assertEquals(1.23, bid.getValue(), 0.0);
    System.out.println(bid);

    bid = new Bid("$3.45");
    assertEquals(3.45, bid.getValue(), 0.0);
    System.out.println(bid);
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public final class Bid {

    private static final CurrencyUnit USD = Monetary.getCurrency("USD");
    private MonetaryAmount bid;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param bidStr the bid
     */
    public Bid(String bidStr) {
        MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
                AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.US)
                .set("pattern", "###.##")
                .build());
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(bidStr)) {
            bidStr = bidStr.trim();
            bidStr = bidStr.startsWith("$") ? bidStr.substring(1) : bidStr;
            try {
                bid = FastMoney.parse(bidStr, format);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                bid = FastMoney.of(0, USD);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param bidDouble the bid
     */
    public Bid(double bidDouble) {
        bid = FastMoney.of(bidDouble, USD);
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return bid.getNumber().doubleValue();
    }
}
```

I would have really liked to be able to parse the `bidStr` with or without the `$` using the single `MonetaryAmountFormat`, but after spending a lot of time trying to find out how to make `$` optional, I gave up.  Unfortunately, I can't even figure out how to make `1.23` get parsed as USD.  Moneta throws a `NullPointerException`.  Am I supposed to set a currency using the `AmountFormatQueryBuilder`?  What are all the keys that can be set using the `AmountFormatQueryBuilder`?  I searched for documentation, but couldn't find any anywhere, except for a couple of common keys, like `pattern`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaMoney does not seem to work well when trying to parse unqualified numbers (like `1.23`).

By default, the `MonetaryAmountFormat` wants you to provide the currency name (like `USD 1.23`):

```
MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(Locale.US);
MonetaryAmount amount = format.parse("USD 1.23");
```

If you set `CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL`, then you can parse by currency name or symbol (so, either `USD 1.23` or `$3.45`):

```
AmountFormatQuery formatQuery = AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.US)
    .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
    .build();
MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(formatQuery);
MonetaryAmount amount1 = format.parse("USD 1.23");
MonetaryAmount amount2 = format.parse("$3.45");
```

That is probably the closest you are going to get with JavaMoney.

If you know you are only getting numbers from the same currency, you might be better off parsing the string elsewhere (with regexs or something) and converting to a consistent input format because (as you discovered), you easily get `NullPointerException`s with no explanation when JavaMoney is unhappy.

As far as the available keys, you can peek at the constants on `org.javamoney.moneta.format.AmountFormatParams`: `pattern`, `groupingSizes`, `groupingSeparators`.

When setting the format, it is important to note that you must use the generic [currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_%28typography%29): `¤`. For instance, you might do `.set("pattern", "¤#,##0.00")`.

Finally, rather than directly using the `FastMoney` class from the Moneta RI, you can parse right from a `MonetaryAmountFormat`:

```
// rather than using Monata directly:
MonetaryAmount amount = FastMoney.parse(bidStr, format);

// use the API:
MonetaryAmount amount = format.parse(bidStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom format pattern then you can parse strings which contains only a number without currency but you should specify the expected currency yourself.
Here is an example:

```
@Test
public void testParse_pattern_without_currency_sign_but_with_currency_in_context() {
    CurrencyUnit usd = Monetary.getCurrency("USD");
    AmountFormatContextBuilder builder = AmountFormatContextBuilder.of(US);
    builder.set(AmountFormatParams.PATTERN, "0.00"); // the pattern doesn't contains a currency sign ¤
    builder.set(CurrencyUnit.class, usd); // set expected currency
    AmountFormatContext context = builder.build();
    DefaultMonetaryAmountFormat format = new DefaultMonetaryAmountFormat(context);
    MonetaryAmount parsedAmount = format.parse("0.01 USD");
    assertSame(parsedAmount.getCurrency(), usd);
    assertEquals(parsedAmount.getNumber().doubleValueExact(), 0.01D);
    assertEquals(parsedAmount.toString(), "USD 0.01");
}
```

Note that you need to create a context with `set(CurrencyUnit.class, usd)`.

But if you try to set a pattern with with the currency sign e.g. `0.00 ¤` then you'll receive an error: `javax.money.format.MonetaryParseException: Error parsing CurrencyUnit: no input`.

I created a ticket [Lenient Formatter: Parse a string with a number but without a currency code](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/issues/294) for this, please read and add your opinion.