# JavaMoney: set CurrencyStyle without a compile-time dependency on moneta

Tags: java, java-money, jsr354

I'm trying to create a `MonetaryAmountFormat` that uses the currency unit symbol:

```
MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
  AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.GERMANY)
                          .set(org.javamoney.moneta.format.CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
                          .set("pattern", "#,##0.##¤")
                          .build()
);
```

(Taken from [How to format MonetaryAmount with currency symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098171/) and [Customizing a MonetaryAmountFormat using the Moneta (JavaMoney) JSR354 implemenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874805/)).

The java/maven project has a dependency on moneta in runtime (not compile-time) scope. It seems that the class `CurrencyStyle` and its value `SYMBOL` are part of moneta, the java-money reference implementation, and not part of the java-money API. Thus, the code does not compile.

I created this ugly workaround:

```
String currencyStyle = "org.javamoney.moneta.format.CurrencyStyle";
final Enum<?> SYMBOL = Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(currencyStyle), "SYMBOL");
MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
  AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.GERMANY)
                          .set(currencyStyle, SYMBOL)
                          .set("pattern", "#,##0.##¤")
                          .build()
);
```

Is it possible to create a `MonetaryAmountFormat` that uses the currency unit symbol without this hack?

Comment: This is not a question but a request of design change for developers.
Please create a ticket here https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/issues

Comment: I created ticket [#83](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/issues/83).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `DecimalFormat` as alternative to `MonetaryAmountFormat` is an option.

Drawbacks:

- Conversion between `Number` and `MonetaryAmount` must be done manually
- Works only when you don't have changing currency units (unit is taken from the format, not from the `MonetaryAmount` object)

Example:

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.##¤", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));

// format
MonetaryAmount source = ...;
String formattedAmount = format.format(source.getNumber());

// parse
Number numberAmount = format.parse(formattedAmount);
MonetaryAmount target = Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory().setCurrency("EUR").setNumber(numberAmount).create()
```